# MySQL: Insert Random Date value dependent on some other date attribute

Tags: mysql, database, date, datetime

In a table X in mysql db i want to insert random anniversary date for every row having date of birth before 1/01/1990 in a new empty column. Please help me out as i m a novice in MySQL

Comment: One way - You can insert using any language script, and other way - using store proceduers!

Comment: What do you mean by *random anniversary date*?

Comment: i mean i just have to populate my db with some random date which should satisfy the above mentioned condition like his anniversary date should be after his dob and should have atleast a gap of 23 years from his birth date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) to generate a random integer in a range (let's say in a range between 23 and 75) like this

```
SELECT FLOOR(23 + RAND() * (75 - 23))
```

Your update statement to fill `anniversary` column of your table then might look like

```
UPDATE person 
   SET anniversary = dob + INTERVAL FLOOR(23 + RAND() * (75 - 23)) YEAR
 WHERE dob < '1990-01-01'
```

Let's do a quick test

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE person 
    -> (
    ->   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   name varchar(32) ,
    ->   dob DATE ,
    ->   anniversary DATE
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO person (name, dob)
    -> VALUES
    -> ('John',   '1972-01-15'),
    -> ('Phil',   '1964-05-23'),
    -> ('Mark',   '1948-12-10'),
    -> ('Steven', '1991-02-28'),
    -> ('Helen',  '1987-07-01');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE person 
    ->    SET anniversary = dob + INTERVAL FLOOR(23 + RAND() * (75 - 23)) YEAR
    ->  WHERE dob  SELECT * FROM person;
+----+--------+------------+-------------+
| id | name   | dob        | anniversary |
+----+--------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | John   | 1972-01-15 | 1999-01-15  |
|  2 | Phil   | 1964-05-23 | 2022-05-23  |
|  3 | Mark   | 1948-12-10 | 1979-12-10  |
|  4 | Steven | 1991-02-28 | NULL        |
|  5 | Helen  | 1987-07-01 | 2050-07-01  |
+----+--------+------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: In the above case anniversary date is going beyond current date, it would have been better if that case was also covered. Anyway thanks for the help.